# Lost root access possibility /sbin/nologin

Tags: linux, root

I accidentally edited the file `/etc/passwd` on my server in the following way:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/sbin/nologin
```

Now I can not login as root. When I enter the `su` command, `Cannot execute /sbin/nologin: No such file or directory` is displayed in console.

I have not physical access to server. I have not users in sudoers file.

OS: Linux 2.6.24-23-server

Can you please help me to login as root?

Answer (score 0):

Boot the system from a Live CD, from which you can mount the filesystem and edit the `etc/passwd` file.

Answer (score 0):

or via grub, add to the end of the kernel line:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

That should do it too.  You may need to mount the filesystem read-write before the edit:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```